# IOS Compare 2 NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

I have 2 arrays,

array1: I have 3 object.

array2: I have 4 object.

I want to compare each object in the 2 arrays.

This is my code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < check1.count; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < check2.count; j++) {
        if ([[check1 objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToArray:[check2 objectAtIndex:j]])
        {
            NSLog(@"same");
            [cellContact.iconnewmessage setHidden:NO];
        }
    }
}
```

But, I had met bug: 
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7b97d280'

Comment: You don't have two arrays. Either `check1` or `check2` actually points to an `NSString`.

Comment: You need to define what you want to do before you can code it. Do you want to see if any of the objects in one array match any of the objects in the other array? If so, you might use the approach you have written, although you could use logic to break out of the loops. If you want to see if the arrays have exactly the same contents then it doesn't make sense to compare an array of 3 objects with an array of 4 objects. We know from the beginning that the arrays are not equal.

Comment: Example: If Array1 have 1 object same with Array2, NSLog 1 object.

If Array1 have 2 object same with Array2, NSLog 2 object.

Comment: I think you overcomplicated your code with 2 'for loops'. Also you want to check if the object on array1 is at the same index position of the array2 or just if the object is at the array2 at all?

Comment: can you write code demo?

Comment: Don't just replace your question with another; ask a *new* question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
int similarObjects = 0;

for (int i=0;i < array1.count;i++)
{
    if ([array2 containsObject:array1[i]])
    {
        NSLog(@"both contains:%@", array1[i]);

        similarObjects++;
    }
}
NSLog(@"similarObjects :%d", similarObjects);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know what you want to do.. 
but if you want to compare values one by one at index..

```
NSArray *array1 = @[@1,@2,@3,@4];
NSArray *array2 = @[@1,@5,@6];

for (int i=0;i < array1.count;i++)
{
    if (array2.count > i)
        if (array1[i] == array2[i])
        {
            NSLog(@"Same:%@ at index:%d", array1[i], i);
        }
}
```

// if checking contents

```
//for counting similar objects
int similarObjects = 0;

for (int i=0;i < array1.count;i++)
{
    if ([array2 containsObject:array1[i]])
    {
        NSLog(@"both contains:%@", array1[i]);

        similarObjects++;
    }
}
NSLog(@"similarObjects :%d", similarObjects);
```

by way `check1` in your code is not an array, and that's causing the error.. 
hope this helped

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to reimplement what the framework can inherently do.

```
if([[NSSet setWithArray:check1] intersectsSet:[NSSet setWithArray:check2]])
{
    NSLog(@"same");
    [cellContact.iconnewmessage setHidden:NO];
}
```

If you want to iterate through an array in general then use `for(ObjectType *object in array)`, don't keep some manual index counter. `NSArray`s have no guaranteed complexity for random accesses.

To access item `i` in an array, just use `array[i]`.